# Is there a formula to compare two number sequences to determine if a number coincides / overlaps?

Tags: math

What will be given are any two number sequences with:

1. Start Number of each sequence
2. Interval of each sequence, after which a number occurs

(Start Number & Interval given in attached image below)

To find a formula:

1. Is it possible to check if a number overlaps between any two given sequences?
2. If yes, on what number will it overlap?
   [image: Image for visual help]

Comment: Can you demonstrate *any* effort at solving this yourself?

Comment: Tried to figure it using attached jpg image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to check if a number overlaps.

The first sequence is `a + n * da`, the second `b + m * db`

```
a + n * da  = b + m * db
n * da - m * db = b - a
```

It is [linear Diophantine equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diophantine_equation#One_equation), it has solutions if

```
(b - a) mod GCD(db, da) == 0
```

where GCD is greatest common divisor

For both your examples GCD of steps is 1, steps are mutual prime, so intersections do exist. While `6 + n * 12, 1 + n * 18` have no intersection

To find general formula for intersection values, solve Diophantine equation (and get a family of solutions). [Arbitrary found example](https://math.libretexts.org/Courses/Mount_Royal_University/MATH_2150%3A_Higher_Arithmetic/5%3A_Diophantine_Equations/5.1%3A_Linear_Diophantine_Equations) (section `Use the following steps to solve` )

Comment: Thanks and can you clarify what (a, b, n, m, d) stand for?

Comment: a is starting element of the first sequence, da is its step, n is number of sequence element, b,db,m - same for the second sequence